# Can I use c # .dll libraries in Android Studio Java / Kotlin?

Tags: java, c#, kotlin, dll, jar

the challenge is this: can I use c # .dll libraries in Android Studio Java / Kotlin or vice versa use .jar libraries in c # projects?
If you have any thoughts on this matter, I will be very glad to them.

Comment: Yep, use Xamarin ... but, you'll need to move over to C# ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin

Comment: @Skin i am working in kotlin/java android studio project and cant switch to Xamarin